# How to rotate a single character based on a specific range of ascii characters in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to come up with a function that accepts a character and a number. The number is the number of times the character should be "rotated". The accepted ASCII codes are 32 to 126.

Example of rotate = If a character "A" was rotated twice, it would end up as the character "C". If "A" was rotated three times, it would end up as the letter "D". If you look at the ASCII table:

http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-0-127.gif

Given my limit of the ASCII value being 32 to 126... ascii value 065 rotated would be ascii value 067. ascii value 124 rotated 5 times would be ascii value 34.

For example:

1. if I passed the function "!" (ASCII code 33) and the number 2, the
   output character should be "#" (ASCII code 35).
2. if I passed "}"
   (ASCII code 125) and the number 3, I should get the output character
   "!" (ASCII code 33).

What is the best way to accomplish this in java (can it support negative numbers for the distance to rotate instead of just positive if you want to rotate the other way around)?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "rotate." Please provide a more complete description of what you want the function to do.

Comment: It smells like homework. Am I right?

Comment: Not homework, just a little challenge I am stumped on after watching the Da Vinci code (theres this box with multiple rings, each with the same set of characters that can be rotated along an axis to open that got me curious about how this could be done programmatically with ASCII).

Comment: [Big] hint: translate the value so that it's 0-based, do the rotation, then translate it back.

Comment: Please explain negative number point with an example. Not clear to me

Comment: If you start with } and rotate forward X times to 1. You should be able to start from 1, and using a negative distance of -X to go back to }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
static char rotate(char c, int distance) {
    assert 32 <= c && c < 127;
    if (distance < 0) distance = distance % (127 - 32) + 127 - 32;
    return (char) ((c + distance - 32) % (127 - 32) + 32);
}
```

Edit: Added the `if (distance`... line to support negative distances.

Comment: Possible to go backwards with a negative distance?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
  public static char numToChar(int num,int rotate){
       int result = num+rotate;
       if(result>126){         
          result =31+(result-126);
       }
       return (char)result;
  }

System.out.println(numToChar(33,2));
System.out.println(numToChar(125,3));
```

**Output**

```
#
!
```

Comment: Possible to go backwards with a negative rotate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach

```
public static char rotateChar(char in, int shift) {
  /* cast char to int */
  int v = (int) in;
  /* to cover wrap-around */
  v += (shift % 95);
  /* 32 - 126 = -95 */
  return (char) ((v > 126) ? v - 95 : v);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.printf("! + 2 = %s\n",
      String.valueOf(rotateChar('!', 2)));
  System.out.printf("} + 3 = %s\n",
      String.valueOf(rotateChar('}', 3)));
  System.out.printf("b - 1 = %s\n",
    String.valueOf(rotateChar('b', -1)));
}

! + 2 = #
} + 3 = !
b - 1 = a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ascii;
    String rotate;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter ASCII Character");
    ascii = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Rotate value");
    rotate = in.nextLine();


    int output=(Integer.parseInt(ascii)+Integer.parseInt(rotate))% 126;

    if(output<32) output=output+32;

    System.out.println("output="+output);
    System.out.println(Character.toString ((char) output));

}
```